# C# WPF httprequest PUT remote server error 400

Tags: c#, httprequest

Hi I am having issues with my code stating this error `An exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.Net.Requests.dll but was not handled in user code The remote server returned an error: (400) .`

Not really sure what went wrong. Also if there is a equivalent httpclient code, that would be really helpful

EDIT: Also to add, the url works on Postman when I do PUT request
EDIT2: Adding cURL from Postman

EDIT2: Adding cURL from Postman

```
curl --location --request PUT 'http://localhost:30010' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "PropertyValue": "test"
}'
```

```
            var url = "http://localhost:30010";

            var httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            httpRequest.Method = "PUT";

            httpRequest.ContentType = "application/json";

            var data = @"{
                ""Name"" = ""Bob""
            }";
            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpRequest.GetRequestStream(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                streamWriter.Write(data);
            }

            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }

            Console.WriteLine(httpResponse.StatusCode);
```

Comment: If it works with postman it maybe about missing some headers in your request, otherwise please post your curl of postman to check detail

Comment: @SaeedEsmaeelinejad sorry but how can i get the curl?

Comment: Nvm, added it now.

Comment: You need to set `ContentLength` property and close the stream, before calling GetResponse

Comment: In the postman you send ``PropertyValue`` in the body but in app you send ``Name``. Why?

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran not really sure what value I put on the ContentLength, do I put 0 or a specific value?

@SaeedEsmaeelinejad I just changed the info on the code, but PropertyValue` is what i will be using

Comment: You need to send the length of the request payload. In above code example, `req.ContentLength=data.Length`